# find the eigenvalues of a matrix using the eigenvalues of another matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let A be the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&4/3&1/3&1/3&0\\0&1/3&4/3&1/3&0\\0&1/3&1/3&4/3&0\\0&0&0&0&3/2\end{bmatrix}
and 1, 1, 1, 1.5 and 2 its eigenvalues.

How can I use this to find the eigenvalues of matrix B \begin{bmatrix}34&33&-33&0&0\\33&103/3&-98/3&1/3&0\\-33&-98/3&103/3&1/3&0\\0&1/3&1/3&4/3&0\\0&0&0&0&3/2\end{bmatrix}
Without computing the characteristic polynomial of B?

Comment: I would look into the fact $1/3-33 = -98/3$ and $4/3 + 33 = 103/3$

Comment: If $A$ is the original matrix, then $B=A+u u^T$, where $u=(1,1,-1,0,0)^T$.

Comment: It is actually A+33u u^T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $A,B$ are block diagonal, with the lower right block consisting of the $1 \times 1 $ block ${ 3 \over 2}$, hence this is one eigenvalue of both.

Let $\tilde{A}, \tilde{B}$ be the upper right $4 \times 4$ block of each.

Note that $\tilde{A} = I + {1 \over 3} u u^T$, where $u=(0,1,1,-1)^T$.

Note that $\tilde{B} = \tilde{A} + 33 w w ^T$, where $w = (1,1,-1, 0)^T$,
and further note that $\langle u , w \rangle = 0$.

It is straightforward to see that if $x \in \operatorname{sp} \{u,w\}^\bot$, then
$\tilde{B}x = \tilde{A}x = x$, hence both have two eigenvalues at $1$.

We see that $\tilde{A}w = w$, and $\tilde{A} u = (1+ {1 \over 3} \|u\|^2) u = 2u$,
hence $\tilde{A}$ has two more eigenvalues
$1,2$.

We see that $\tilde{B} u = \tilde{A} u = 2 u$ and
$\tilde{B} w = (1+ 33 \|w\|^2) w = 100 w$, hence $\tilde{B}$ has two more
eigenvalue at $2,100$.